# AngularJS Filter parameter with undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I made filter for search in table data, but the parameter always is 'undefined'

I use it with **ng-repeat** like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText"  class="form-control" translate="Search">
<tr ng-repeat="g in StudentList  | SearchFilter:searchText >
```

and the filter:

```
app.filter('SearchFilter', function () {
    return function (input, word) {
        if (word == undefined || word == '')
            return input;
        // filtering ...
    }
});
```

I use AngularJS v1.5.8 on chrome browser

Comment: I think the problem is by translate plugin witch takes and isolate model
It added by mistake sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filtering a normal object you don't need a custom filter. just use `filter:searchText` like this example:

```js
var app=angular.module('app',[])
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope){
$scope.StudentList=[
  { id: 1, name: 'John', address: 'Highway 71'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Peter', address: 'Lowstreet 4'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Amy', address: 'Apple st 652'},
  { id: 4, name: 'Hannah', address: 'Mountain 21'},
  { id: 5, name: 'Michael', address: 'Valley 345'},
  { id: 6, name: 'Sandy', address: 'Ocean blvd 2'},
  { id: 7, name: 'Betty', address: 'Green Grass 1'},
  { id: 8, name: 'Richard', address: 'Sky st 331'},
  { id: 9, name: 'Susan', address: 'One way 98'},
  { id: 10, name: 'Vicky', address: 'Yellow Garden 2'},
  { id: 11, name: 'Ben', address: 'Park Lane 38'},
  { id: 12, name: 'William', address: 'Central st 954'},
  { id: 13, name: 'Chuck', address: 'Main Road 989'},
  { id: 14, name: 'Viola', address: 'Sideway 1633'}
];
})
```

```css
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input ng-model="searchText">
  <table border=1>
    <tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Ardress</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="g in StudentList|filter:searchText"><td>{{g.id}}</td><td>{{g.name}}</td><td>{{g.address}}</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I making search in all object proprieties will it works?

Comment: yes it will  works, I will make a example for you just moment

Answer (score 0):

Yes according to the filter you have in tr element, it accepts only one parameter. If you want two parameters to be passed, you should change the filter as,

```
 <tr ng-repeat="g in StudentList  | filter:filterUser(searchText, word)>

 $scope.filterUser = function(input, word) {
 return function (input, word) {
        if (word == undefined || word == '')
            return input;
        // filtering ...
    }
}
```

But i dont understand why you need  a custom filter in this case, you could just do like this,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" >
<tr ng-repeat="g in StudentList  | filter:searchText">
```